# How can I determine the length of an array using typeof() in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

Can I use the typeof() method( 'Type' class ) to determine the length of an array?

I have a method like this:

```
public void Foo<T>(T data)
{
    Type t = typeof(T);
    if(t.isArray)
    {
        // determine array length here
        ...
    }
}
```

You'll notice that the input to the above method DOES NOT have the array modifier([]). This is because the input does not have to be an array. I already know that I can write two overloads for this method but would like to know how to utilize the 'Type' class...

Comment: Could you not just cast it at that point inside your if statement. eg `((Array)data).Count` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `System.Array` is the base class for array types:

```
public void Foo<T>(T data)
{
    Type t = typeof(T);
    if(t.IsArray)
    {
        int length = ((Array)(object)data).Length;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dynamic` to easily accomplish this.

```
public void Foo<T>(T data)
{
    Type t = typeof(T);
    if (t.isArray)
    {
        int length = ((dynamic)data).Length;
    }
}
```